# Pandas rename operation change column name on two columns instead of one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
      PRESTASJON  PRESTASJON   GRUPPE   GRUPPE
BIB#                                          
1       1.097535    1.152557   RANDOM   RANDOM
2       1.019290    1.060228  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
3       1.078993    1.117647  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
4       1.068155    1.136278  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
5       1.001602    1.049030  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
6       0.999831    1.086611   RANDOM   RANDOM
7       1.079463    1.129667   RANDOM   RANDOM
8       1.053904    1.122307   RANDOM   RANDOM
9       1.146811    1.156933  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
10      1.019548    1.086616  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
11      1.026948    1.085549  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
12      1.094309    1.130020   RANDOM   RANDOM
13      1.210418    1.197499  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
14      1.024908    1.054702   RANDOM   RANDOM
15      0.981332    1.003535   RANDOM   RANDOM
16      1.160070    1.204359   RANDOM   RANDOM
```

For my analysis, I needed to perform a pivot operation which resulted in two identical column names. I want the column name with index 0 to be 'POST' and the column name with index 1 to be 'PRE'.

I have tried:

```
mapping = {df.columns[0]:'post', df.columns[1]: 'pre'}
df = df.rename(columns=mapping)
```

But this changes the column names on both the columns:

```
           pre       pre   GRUPPE   GRUPPE
BIB#                                      
1     1.097535  1.152557   RANDOM   RANDOM
2     1.019290  1.060228  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
3     1.078993  1.117647  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
4     1.068155  1.136278  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
5     1.001602  1.049030  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
6     0.999831  1.086611   RANDOM   RANDOM
7     1.079463  1.129667   RANDOM   RANDOM
8     1.053904  1.122307   RANDOM   RANDOM
9     1.146811  1.156933  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
10    1.019548  1.086616  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
11    1.026948  1.085549  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
12    1.094309  1.130020   RANDOM   RANDOM
13    1.210418  1.197499  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
14    1.024908  1.054702   RANDOM   RANDOM
15    0.981332  1.003535   RANDOM   RANDOM
16    1.160070  1.204359   RANDOM   RANDOM
```

, which is not what I want. Can someone please guide me to a good solution?

Comment: How are created such dataframe? Maybe there should be possible avoid this problem.

Comment: I don't think I have used the best solution. But I have two similar .csv files that I have parsed into a dataframe. Then, I have concatenated them using df = pd.concat([pre, post]). Next, I used df = df.pivot('BIB#','DAG'). This resulted in a multiindex. I then dropped the first index level by using df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0). I'm sure this is not the best approach :/

Comment: But why removed `MultiIndex` ? I edit answer for solution.

Comment: Yes, that's probably a better solution, I guess. I want to remove the multiindex so that I can create a csv file that it is easy to work with in d3.js.

Comment: How looks Multiindex before removing? `print (df.columns.tolist())`

Comment: Maybe `df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)` should help

Comment: print(df.columns.tolist()) resulted in: [('PRESTASJON', 'POST'), ('PRESTASJON', 'PRE'), ('GRUPPE', 'POST'), ('GRUPPE', 'PRE')]

Comment: So for avoid `duplicated columns` is possible not remove first level, but use `df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)`

Comment: Thank you! So I asked the wrong question :/

Comment: No problem ;) I only ask for avoid this problem, it is possible so super

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem with first attempt

The reason that you're getting both columns renamed to the same value is because your `mapping` is defined by reference to two column names with the same `str` content at all times in your attempt (below).

```py
mapping = {df.columns[0]:'post', df.columns[1]: 'pre'}
df = df.rename(columns=mapping)
```

This code essentially runs as "Rename columns where content is the same as `df.columns[0]` to `'post'`, then rename columns where content is the same as `df.columns[1]` to `'pre'`". Since `df.columns[0] == df.columns[1]` when the above is executed, both columns are being renamed - first to `'post'` then to `'pre'`.

### Solution

Since you know the indices of the columns you wish to rename, you could rename each explicitly by index as follows.

```py
df.columns.values[0] = 'post'
df.columns.values[1] = 'pre'
```

Running the above on the `df` outlined in your question will result in:

```py
          post       pre   GRUPPE   GRUPPE
BIB#                                      
1     1.097535  1.152557   RANDOM   RANDOM
2     1.019290  1.060228  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
3     1.078993  1.117647  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
4     1.068155  1.136278  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
5     1.001602  1.049030  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
6     0.999831  1.086611   RANDOM   RANDOM
7     1.079463  1.129667   RANDOM   RANDOM
8     1.053904  1.122307   RANDOM   RANDOM
9     1.146811  1.156933  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
10    1.019548  1.086616  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
11    1.026948  1.085549  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
12    1.094309  1.130020   RANDOM   RANDOM
13    1.210418  1.197499  BLOCKED  BLOCKED
14    1.024908  1.054702   RANDOM   RANDOM
15    0.981332  1.003535   RANDOM   RANDOM
16    1.160070  1.204359   RANDOM   RANDOM
```

Comment: That worked and now I know why my code didn't work!

Answer (score 1):

You can set new columns by lists:

```
df.columns = ['post1','pre1','post2', 'pre2']
```

Or:

```
df.columns = ['post','pre'] + df.columns[2:].tolist()
```

EDIT:

After some discussion better is not remove first level, but join `MultiIndex` levels for avoid `duplicated columns names`:

```
df = pd.concat([pre, post])
df = df.pivot('BIB#','DAG')

df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
```